# Bootstrap 3.3.2 - Can I have more than 12 rows?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to split the row space I have to 13 columns, not 12. Every time I had the 13th column my row breaks into rows, regardless of the width of the container. So 12 is fixed/

How do I define 13 columns?

I tried:

```
<div class="col-lg-13">
  <div class="row little-padding">
```

I also tried:

```
<div class="row little-padding col-lg-13">
```

But still, 12 per row remains...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom version of Bootstrap, and specify the number of columns you want it to work with via the official site.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

That link takes you directly to the grid system components.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like your grid system to be 13 columns instead of 12, then you would have to modify the bootstrap LESS template. You can download this from getbootstrap.com.

(13 is an odd choice though)

The variable you are going to need to modify is: `@grid-columns` which is defined as 12 by default. You may also want/need to modify some additional things such as `@grid-gutter-width` which is 30px by default.

Comment: I'd say it's an unlucky choice.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap was made for a 12-col usage.

If you want to have more columns, you need to define your custom responsive grid, with the help of Bootstrap Less variables ([see here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)). You'll mainly need to change these variables :

`@grid-columns:` Number of columns in the grid.

`@grid-gutter-width` Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.

Answer (score 0):

You can [**customize**](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) your bootstrap and get more col's, but ist **not** recommended. 12 is a good number - stay with it.

**updated**

If I'm not mistaking, bootstrap switched to 12 from 16-based grid for several reasons: a) reduces amount of supported `css` and b) division by 3 which provides more flexibility for different devices.

Keep in mind, Bootstrap promotes mobile first designs, which kind of assumes you taking to consideration tablets as well.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation for why it's not recommended?

Comment: @MattD I'd say 12 is a good choice because of it's divisibility. It can be divided by 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, and 12. That 's a lot more than 13 which can be divided by 1 and 13. Not good for trying to line up stacked grids with different cell dimensions.

Comment: Agreed, but OP should still provide an explanation in their answer as to why. Simply saying something isn't recommended doesn't make it so. For that matter, 13 may not be recommended, but something like 24 could, so clarification is also desirable. :)

Comment: @MattD I kind of walked into this trap myself, didn't I? :) Original question was `How do I define 13 columns?` which I provided answer to, should've stop right there -)

Comment: @DejaVu I disagree. Sure they provide a way to do it, but you do raise a valid point. I was simply asking that you elaborate more on your point rather than simply saying, "It's not recommended." Well, why isn't it recommended? That's all. :D